# Where can i find a new ndk-build file?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I made a mistake and opened ndk-build in wordpad, then saved it, but the problem is wordpad added formatting which messed up my ndk-build. i looked all over the net and haven't been able to find the full source or download for ndk-build. ndk-buil.cmd works, but i'd like to have ndk-build too. is the only way to get a new version by reinstalling the entire android ndk?

Comment: It's inside the android ndk folder

Comment: i know where it is on my computer, i need a new one because the one on my computer is no good now... how would i have opened it in wordpad if i couldn't find it on my computer?

Comment: you have to be joking, you can't just show me a link to it then? I've searched all over for ndk-build source and download links. where can i download just the ndk-build file, or get the files code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you can do it this way:

1. Re-download your ndk-version from google:
   replace **[VERSION]** with your ndk-version, for example **r7c**
   replace **[SYSTEM]** with **windows**, **darwin-x86** or **linux-x86**
   repacle **[FORMAT]** with **zip** for windows system or with **tar.bz2** for linux or mac
   http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-[VERSION]-[SYSTEM].[FORMAT]
   **example:** http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r6a-windows.zip
2. Then unpack it and replace your *ndk-build* with the one out of the package.
   Now it should work again.

I hope that I could help you.

Comment: THANK you for a useful reply! I was actually looking for a link to just that file or its code though so i won't have to redownload the entire ndk, but thanks all the same

Comment: @iedoc: you really don't want to download this small file separately because it should match the version of the other files.

Answer (score 1):

Just redownload the whole NDK. It has no internal configuration that won't be restored on the next run.